# Does Wikidata offer inferencing/reasoning?

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I would like to use RDFS level inferencing in some queries posed in the Wikidata Query Service which uses SPARQL. Does it support inferencing/reasoning? If so, in what kind? For example, is it Forward Chaining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test that by inspecting the results of executing a query that assumes reasoning. For example, `subclass of` in RDFS is a transitive property. Therefore, querying for `subclass of` `author`, should return both its direct and indirect subclasses. [Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fauthor%20%3FauthorLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fauthor%20wdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ482980.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?author ?authorLabel 
WHERE 
{
  ?author wdt:P279 wd:Q482980.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

When I executed it, it returned 28 results. However, finding the subclasses of `writer`, which is a `subclass of` `author`, returns 71 results, more than the `author`. [Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fauthor%20%3FauthorLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fauthor%20wdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ36180.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?author ?authorLabel 
WHERE 
{
  ?author wdt:P279 wd:Q36180.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

This means that inferencing is not supported at the time of writing this answer, since when searching for `author` subclasses, it should have returned the subclasses of `writer` too (and its subclasses' subclasess etc.).

One workaround is to use, [property paths](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial/en#Property_paths). For example, entering the below query, even without inferencing, will return all subclasses of `author` in any level. [Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fauthor%20%3FauthorLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fauthor%20wdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ482980.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?author ?authorLabel 
WHERE 
{
  ?author wdt:P279* wd:Q482980.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

By appending `*` to the `wdt:P279` property, means a sequence of 0 or more `subclass of` properties.

Conducting a short research on the web, I have found two sources: [[1]](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Reasoning), [[2]](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Reasoning/Use_cases), from Wikidata, that are about the support of reasoning and inferencing. It is a really useful feature and I hope we will see it in the future.